# Equation created from Functions

Tags: functions

I have an equation with the variables x and y, for this example let's say it's:

$a = (x(x+y-xy))+(x+y-xy)-(x(x+y-xy))(x+y-xy)$

The output of this equation `(a)`, as well as the inputs `x` and `y` can **only** be a `0` or `1`

I also have the following functions:

- $f(x) = 1-x$
- $g(x,y) = xy$
- $h(x,y) = f(g(f(x), f(y))) = 1-(1-x)(1-y) = x+y-xy$

I am trying to find a way to 'simplify' `a`, which means it uses the least amount of the functions above, and the functions above **only**

Overview:

1. What process can I use to 'simplify' any equation `(a)` with any set of functions?
2. What process can I use to 'simplify' any equation `(a)` with any amount of variables (in the example, x and y were used. How could this be done if the variables were x, y and z)
3. If I have multiple equations, how can I 'simplify' them both, but once a function has been used (for example `g(xy,y)`), if that function comes up again in the same equation or any other equation , it doesn't count towards the total amount of functions used. (The logic for this is that if I've already worked out what `g(xy,y)` is, I don't need to work it out again)

Note: For the example with equation `a`, it can be simplified to `a = h(x,y)`

Note2: **All** functions can be written as a combination of f(x) and g(x,y)

Comment: If inputs are $(x,y)$ and $x,y  = 0, 1$ there are $2^2 =4$ possible inputs.  $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$.  if the output is $0,1$ there are only $2^4$ possible functions.  Find the simpliest express for each of the sixteen and out which ones these are.

Comment: That's perfectly feasible for only two inputs x and y, however what if there are more variables? (In my case there could be hundreds) @fleablood

Comment: Are you familiar with boolean logic.  $1-x = \lnot x$ and $xy = x \land y$ and $x+y - xy = x \lor y$....

Comment: "however what if there are more variables?" then that would be a different question.  What if Moby Dick were a tiny minnow?

Comment: And for $a$ just factor it: $(x(x+y-xy))+(x+y-xy)-(x(x+y-xy))(x+y-xy) = (x + 1 - x)(x+y-xy)^2 = (x+y-xy)^2$.  all input/output is $0$ or $1$, $w^2 = w$ so $a = x+y-xy$.

Comment: @fleablood I have included it in the overview section of my question. There's no point asking three separate questions, since they are all extremely similar with only very minor changes being made. Boolean logic is a great point, however the only solutions I can find involve brute force, which isn't an option due to time constraints. If you have an answer, please submit it!

Comment: If you use boolean logic you have three basic functions:  $\lnot m = 1-m$ and $m\land n = mn$ and $m\lor n= (m+ n - mn)$.  So $a = (x\land(x\lor y)) + (x\lor y) - (x\land(x\lor y))(x\lor y) = (x\land (x \lor y)) \lor (x\lor y) = (x) \lor (x\lor y) = x\lor y = x + y -xy$.

Comment: @fleablood Great answer to solving a single equation, but what if there are multiple equations, as described on section 3 of the overview?

Comment: "but what if there are multiple equations, as described on section 3 of the overview?"  I'm sorry.  But my answer every question in thirty seconds calculator is on the fritz.  You asked for advice and hints.  My advice and hints is to view this as boolean logic and basic functions.

Comment: @fleablood Ok, thanks a lot for your advice. I'll have a look to see if there are any effective methods to simplify a few thousand equations with a few thousand inputs. If you have any more ideas on a method not including brute force (that's all I can find), please let me know! Have a nice day.